# How to get title from any link using react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hyperlink

how i can get any link/page title using react

Supposed i have a link  [Product](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/A-High-Performance-high-quality-4_1600128942388.html?spm=a2700.13765215.0.0.250115c5cdfSrZ)  , i want to get `<title>A High Performance High Quality 4 Wheeler Quad Bike Atv For Kids And Adult 125cc 250cc 4x4 Atv Loncin - Buy Atv Loncin 250cc 4x4,Atv Car For Kids,High Quality Atv Product on Alibaba.com</title>`  this title.

so i get only "A High Performance High Quality 4 Wheeler Quad Bike Atv For Kids And Adult 125cc 250cc 4x4 Atv Loncin - Buy Atv Loncin 250cc 4x4,Atv Car For Kids,High Quality Atv Product on Alibaba.com"

Comment: Do you mean [title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)?

Comment: yes full title attribute

Comment: If I understand correctly, what about https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-title-9e7f6 ?

Comment: no actually suppose i paste this link in a search bar and from that link it will show me the full title of this link, every time i paste a link there will be different link

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I would start by getting the html from that product page and then navigating that html using normal getElementsByClassName or querySelector kind of methods. You might need to parse that HTML response first, but I would Imagine it would look something like this (assuming you use axios):

```
axios.get(`https://whatever.store/product-one`)
.then(res => {

   const title = res.getElementById('id-of-element').title

   //this.setState({ title: title}) or whatever you plan to do next
})
.catch(err => { console.log(err)})
```

Comment: what to do if i don't have any ```id-of-element```

Comment: Check what W3Schools is offering https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp